# Attach angular click listener on a dynamically created html element

Tags: angularjs

I am adding a few buttons dynamically by injecting html using jquery. I want to be able to use ng-click on those elements but I do not know how to attach an angular click listener on it.

Comment: Don't use jQuery. Do it the Angular way, with directives. Then the ng-click will be compiled by Angular.

Answer (score 1):

To attach a click listener on a button simply add ng-click="someMethod()" to the button:

```
<button ng-click="someMethod()">Button text</button>
```

you will need have to have a scope-method called someMethod().

for reference see the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and note that the expression can be replaced by a method.

Comment: That does not work when I add content dynamially, for ex: $('#parentDiv').html('<button ng-click="someMethod()" >click me</button>');
This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: The reason it is not working is that you add your element in the controller. You should probably use a directive instead. Alternatively a service. You could also use pure javascript as in this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/q49iHdndKhZ1Kipkx3Nn?p=preview). What are you trying to accomplish, and why do you need to add it dynamically in the controller?